# mpstat not displaying intr/s column

Tags: linux, performance-monitoring

I'm on CentOS 6.5, sysstat 9.0.4.22.el6

For some reason mpstat is not displaying the intr/s column

I'm running it this way, for example, and only these columns get displayed:

```
mpstat -P ALL 1 5

Average:     CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest
```

Any idea why could that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really strange,I am trying to replicate this issue in my system

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.10 (Final)
$  mpstat -P ALL
Linux 2.6.18-371.9.1.el5 (test)     08/30/2014

 02:23:48 PM  CPU   %user   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal   %idle    intr/s
 02:23:48 PM  all    0.13    0.00    0.07    0.10    0.01    0.01    0.00   99.69    104.26
 02:23:48 PM    0    0.18    0.00    0.08    0.14    0.02    0.02    0.00   99.56    103.96
 02:23:48 PM    1    0.08    0.00    0.06    0.05    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.81      0.30
```

So till Centos5 series look like there is no issue

Now in my Centos6.2,I try to install first sysstat rpm comes with Centos6(sysstat-9.0.4-11.el6.x86_64.rpm) default one is sysstat-9.0.4-18.el6.x86_64.rpm

```
[root@centos ~]# rpm -ivh sysstat-9.0.4-11.el6.x86_64.rpm
warning: sysstat-9.0.4-11.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID  fd431d51: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
1:sysstat                ########################################### [100%]
```

and I am able to replicate the issue

I check the change log and there is nothing much in related to mpstat or this change

```
[root@centos ~]# rpm -q --changelog sysstat|grep -i mpstat
fix the output of mpstat for cpu which are switched off
fix the mpstat output on tickless kernel
- Resolves: #442801 mpstat shows one extra cpu
```

So I am not sure what RedHat has changed,the only thing I found out is https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=624130 .If you need interrupt field use this command instead

```
 [root@centos Packages]# mpstat -A 1 2
  Linux 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 (centos.test.com)   08/31/2014      _x86_64_        (3 CPU)

12:00:33 AM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
12:00:34 AM  all    0.49    0.00    0.49    0.00    0.00    1.46    0.00    0.00   97.57
12:00:34 AM    0    0.00    0.00    1.59    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.41
12:00:33 AM  CPU    intr/s
12:00:34 AM  all   1896.00
12:00:34 AM    0      9.00
12:00:34 AM    1     12.00
12:00:34 AM    2      1.00
```

or use 
                  **mpstat -I ALL**

as per man page

```
    -A     This option is equivalent to specifying -I ALL -u -P ALL

   -I { SUM | CPU | ALL }
          Report interrupts statistics.
```